# How to mock test Flask endpoints that mainly interact with 3rd party APIs?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

We have developed various services using Flask, and all of them really act as an intermediary between the enduser and various 3rd party APIs (but no databases). I have developed tests using pytest with a test_client fixture etc and it works well. But each time a route/endpoint is called by one of the tests, it actually interacts with the 3rd party APIs.

What is the proper way to make mock tests in this situation? I am wondering if I should just develop an exact copy of the endpoints, but simulate the lines where requests to 3rd party APIs occur. That seems like a lot of work, but if I were to just return some expected JSON from a given endpoint then I don't think the code would be tested very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scenarios where you need to call third-party API, you could consider using [Pytest VCR](https://pytest-vcr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

It is a pytest plugin that allow recording of all http requests made inside a test method or function by using a decorator as follow.

```py
@pytest.mark.vcr()
def my_test():
   """
   Example of a function that test a client doing http requests
   """
   some_client = SomeClient()
   some_client.authenticate()
   resource = some_client.get_resource("foo")
   assert resource is not None
```

First time you run your test, calls are recorded into a file called a "cassette". Then subsequents run of this test will use this cassette as a kind of mock instead of sending real http calls.

It works as well if you are testing a flask application views in which https calls are done.

**Be careful** as this solution implies that if you change tested code in a way that add http calls, the test will break as new calls wont exists in the cassette. You will either have to delete cassette and record it again, or run your test with `--vcr-record=new_episodes` to add new calls to existing cassette.

Comment: oh this is great. After looking at the docs this is going to be a big help.